# org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker circular reference Spring Boot 2.1.3

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I just upgraded my app from Spring Boot 1.5.9 to 2.1.3. We have 2 databases, one non sharded and the other one is sharded. When trying to start the application, i get the following error:

```
┌─────┐
|  shardedDataSource defined in class path resource [com/config/ShardedDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  globalNamedParameterJdbcTemplate defined in class path resource [com/config/GlobalDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  globalJdbcTemplate defined in class path resource [com/config/GlobalDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  global defined in class path resource [com/config/GlobalDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker
└─────┘
```

In GlobalDataSourceConfig i have the following Beans

```
@Bean(name = "global")
    public DataSource globalDataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean(name = "globalJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate globalJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(globalDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name="globalNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate globalNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(globalJdbcTemplate());
    }
```

And for the shardedDataSource in ShardedDataSourceConfig class i have

```
  @Primary @Bean @Profile("!test")
    public DataSource shardedDataSource(@Qualifier("globalNamedParameterJdbcTemplate") NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
```

Anyone can give me an idea why this happens?

Before the upgrade this was not happening.

I found a similar issue but the solution is not working for SpringBoot 2

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9394

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by removing the @Primary annotation on the shardedDataSource.  Since a Qualifier is used for globalNamedParameterJdbcTemplate, it automatically does the initialization of the beans correctly.